# What is a citation style that mentions full details of a paper?

Tags: citation-style

Many papers in STEM fields use IEEE or ACM citation styles. However, those use abbreviations for names and journals. Is there a style that mention all paper details with no abbreviations and no doi.

Something simple like:

**Firstname Lastname and Firstname2 Lastname2. Title of the publication. Journal name (Issue), Startpage - Endgpage, Publisher, Year.**

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why are you looking for such a style? If you are submitting a manuscript, you'll follow the journal's style, and if you are just writing your own manuscript, you can format your references whatever way you want.

Comment: E.g. RevTeX with "longbibliography" option. In any case, I wouldn't call details *full* without a DOI identifier.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I have seen it in some documents (theses mainly) and I would like to know if it is available or custom style.

Comment: I heard that some astronomy journals actually use unabbreviated journal names in citations, but I do not have more details right now.

Comment: @StephanKolassa: One reason where a related information is useful is if you want to build a citation database and want to know whether storing something like the full journal name is worth bothering.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I always put the full citation in my BibTeX files and let it choose how to represent them based on where I'm sending it. Is that not how other citation databases work?

Comment: @BillBarth: Conversion from full journal names to abbreviated journal names is unfortunately error-prone and storing both requires additional maintenance. If no publisher relevant for you cares about unabbreviated journal names (which is the case for our group, despite being interdisciplinary), it is thus much more economical just to store abbreviated journal names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the [APSA citation style](http://citesource.trincoll.edu/apsa/apsa.html) recommends full author names in its style guide. I'm more used to an [APA citation style myself](http://citesource.trincoll.edu/apa/index.html), but that does abbreviate first names. Oh, and I *conpletely* agree with [Piotr Migdal](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/49/piotr-migdal) in the comments that a citation that could use a DOI but doesn't is just plain wrong.

Comment: APSA write the full name, but "Lastname, Firstname" and it also mentions DOI https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=apsa

Comment: It uses LastFirst for the first author, since it uses the first author's last name for in-text references and those are easier to look up alphabetically. I think other authors use FirstLast. No modern citation style is *not* going to mention DOIs, given how fantastically useful they are in finding cited scientific articles.

Comment: This will be very difficult to adhere to. When I began maintaining a bibliography, I had a fit of perfectionism and tried to store the full first names of all authors. It needed only a handful of publications until I ran into one for which I could not obtain those names by any reasonable means.